unexpected successful requests in Apache log
I serve a few pages from Apache (v. 2.4.38) and have only notified one person of the paths to the pages.  He says he has not shared the paths and does not use a proxy server.  For the most part the apache access log shows only requests for those pages from that one person's (static) IP (together with the usual denied random known-weakness requests).
But recently the log shows some requests for a few files on those pages from other IPs.  For example, I see:
54.201.227.182 - - [07/Aug/2024:14:34:32 -0700] "GET /local/path/aurora.mkv HTTP/1.1" 200 5025320 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; PPC Mac OS X 10.10; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0"
35.167.184.80 - - [07/Aug/2024:14:34:34 -0700] "GET /local/path/aurora.mkv HTTP/1.1" 200 73572232 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"

Here I've obfuscated my local path and filename, but not the originating IPs.  The requested files actually exist on my server.  The requesting IPs always resolve to something like ec2-IP-address-in-reverse.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.
My Apache is configured to not allow proxy requests, no other pages link to these paths, and my robots.txt file is:
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

I am not being flooded with these mysterious requests but am very curious as to where they come from, how the originator learned my local paths, and whether I should be concerned about this. Could this be some sort of caching process? I only serve http - could someone be sniffing the urls, as unlikely as that sounds?

My guess: MS Browsers have a long tradition of eavesdropping URLs requested by users. And I assume that Chrome does the same. Which means that some big companies well known fir their "creative handling of privacy rules" know about those pages. And use that data. But that is just a guess, obviously.
